# Programmatically press enter with Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to programmatic press the enter key once a value has been set to specific cell:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    If TextBox1.Text = "ALC Test" Then
        Range("$F$2").Value = "17"
        ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    End If
    If TextBox1.Text = "ALC Prod" Then
        Range("$F$2").Value = "54"
        ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    End If
    If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
        Range("$F$2").Value = ""
        ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    End If
End Sub
```

So that I can trigger in excel the refresh of my table
But that does not to seam to work correctly

[image]

Comment: Your question is actually not pressing the enter key, but you want excel to recalculate (refresh) your table after a value is updated using vba. Is that correct?

Comment: @davejal Yes that is

Comment: try `ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll` as I edited in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [sendkeys](http://www.contextures.com/excelvbasendkeys.html) is correct.

---

If you just want to recalculate (refresh) your table data, you could do the following:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

If TextBox1.Text = "ALC Test" Then
        Range("$F$2").Value = "17"
        Range("$F$2").Select
        Application.SendKeys("~")
```

In your situation, you need to select the cell (that holds the parameters) before the enter command is send to excel.

Comment: Thanks allot for your answer yes I did that but somehow the excel  refresh is not getting triggered to update my tabel

Comment: I edited my answer, depending on what you actually want to achieve there are more options

Comment: I am sorry if that was not clear from original question: I type in my text box for example "ALC Test" then in the cell F2 the number 17 appears. The cell F2 has been set as a parameter field on witch my table is updating the part of updating the field is not working , i think that is not getting triggered since there is no enter input when I do it like that manually it works fine

Comment: Thanks for you effort ! but I am sorry still nothing happens .. update my question code

Comment: could your provide some more details? How is the table refreshed when using the enter key? Using a filter or macro ?

Comment: The tabel in question that should get refreshed is a tabel that was create with a MC Query calling a stored procedure with one parameter.  The parameter is getting update like this have a look at the screen shot

Comment: I think I know what the problem is, you need to select the cell one which you press enter to make it work

Comment: hmm well that is more or less how you would do it manually, maybe could be ?

Comment: check my last edit `Range("$F$2").Select` before the sendkeys, not sure if the `$` are needed

Answer (score 0):

What you do is: change the value, and then press "enter" , which has no effect.

Use

```
calculate
```

or

```
activesheet.calculate
```

edited to make it clear:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
If TextBox1.Text = "ALC Test" Then
    Range("$F$2").Value = "17"
    calculate
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for your answer can you give me a bit more context to where I hace to set that ? or instead of what ?

Comment: Just replace your sendkey line with one of those :)

Comment: like that  Application.Calculate ("~")